# MP3 Cover Art Tagging in C#

Tags: c#, tags, mp3, cover

I need to tag MP3 files with a Cover Art in C#...

Is there any easy way to do this? I found UltraID3Lib as an exampel and it is great for regular ID3 tagging but I cant handle the cover art. If someone know an easy way to do this would it be great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something like [this](http://www.mkoby.com/2007/03/21/mp3s-ultraid3lib/):

```
private static void FixAlbumArt(FileInfo MyFile)
{
  //Find the jpeg file in the directory of the Mp3 File
  //We will embed this image into the ID3v2 tag
  FileInfo[] fiAlbumArt = MyFile.Directory.GetFiles("*.jpg");
  if (fiAlbumArt.Length &lt; 1)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("No Album Art Found in {0}", MyFile.Directory.Name);
    return;
  }
  string AlbumArtFile = fiAlbumArt[0].FullName;

  //Create Mp3 Object
  UltraID3 myMp3 = new UltraID3();
  myMp3.Read(MyFile.FullName);
  ID3FrameCollection myArtworkCollection =
    myMp3.ID3v23Tag.Frames.GetFrames(MultipleInstanceFrameTypes.Picture);

  if (myArtworkCollection.Count &gt; 0)
  {//Get Rid of the Bad Embedded Artwork
    #region Remove All Old Artwork
    for (int i = 0; i &lt; myArtworkCollection.Count; i++)
    {
      ID3PictureFrame ra = (ID3PictureFrame)myArtworkCollection[0];
      try
      {
        myMp3.ID3v23Tag.Frames.Remove(FrameTypes.Picture);
      }
      catch { }
    }
    myArtworkCollection.Clear();

     //Save out our changes so that we are working with the
    //most up to date file and tags
    myMp3.ID3v23Tag.WriteFlag = true;
    myMp3.Write();
    myMp3.Read(MyFile.FullName);
    #endregion Remove All Old Artwork
  }
  //Create a PictureFrame object, pointing it at the image on my PC
  ID3PictureFrame AlbumArt =
    new ID3PictureFrame(
    (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(AlbumArtFile),
    PictureTypes.CoverFront, "Attached picture", TextEncodingTypes.ISO88591);
  myMp3.ID3v23Tag.Frames.Add(AlbumArt);
  myMp3.ID3v23Tag.WriteFlag = true;
  myMp3.Write();

  myMp3 = null;
}
```

I'm at work and forgot to turn on Foldershare so I can't show you my trimmed down version where I pass in an Image object but this has everything you'd need to get the job done with a bit of hacking.  Good luck.

Comment: Nice, thanks... I will try it as soon as I get home and leave a comment :D